# Optimization of parameter for recursive Cauchy sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization, recurrence-relations, cauchy-sequences, discrete-optimization

I have the following recursive sequence I'm analyzing:

$$V_0 = 50, V_1 = (1-10k)V_0,$$

$$V_{n+1} = (1-10k)V_n - 5kV_{n-1}$$

where $k > 0$ is a parameter that I'm investigating by running simulations in `R`.

(This is from the "docking problem" in Meerschaert's "Mathematical Modeling").

$\langle V \rangle$ isn't Cauchy for all $k$. The sequence seems to diverge if $k > 0.18$ or so.

My analysis is to examine how fast the sequence converges as $k$ varies. I did this by simulating the sequence and picking the first $n$ for which $|V_n| < 0.1$

Here's a plot of said $n$ as a function of $k$. The horizontal axis are various $k$'s, and the vertical axis is the first $n$ for which $|V_n| < 0.1$ with that $k$ as the parameter.

[image]

[image]

My question is: **What is this function**? Why does it behave the way it does?

How do I find local minima of this function other than by simulation?

And what is the exact $k$ at which the sequence $\langle V \rangle$ stops being Cauchy?

Comment: Is really ${V_0} = 0$ ?

Comment: @Frieder Corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following.

In despite of your graphs suggest detrministic chaotic behavior, like the sequence generated by the [logistic map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map), but this is not the case, because it is a usual second order recurrence, so your graphs show an  effect of the computational approach.

It is clear that the sequence $\{V_n\}$ is uniquely determined by the recurrent formulas and the initial conditions. Consider the characteristic polynomial $$p(\lambda)=\lambda^2+(10k-1)\lambda+5k$$ of the recurrence. It has discriminant

$D=100k^2-40k+1$ (with roots $k=\frac{2\pm \sqrt{3}}{10}$)

and roots

$\lambda_1=\frac{1-10k+\sqrt{D}}2$ and $\lambda_2=\frac{1-10k-\sqrt{D}}2$.

If $D\ne 0$ then $\lambda_1\ne\lambda_2$, so we should search the formula for a sequence $\{V_n\}$ in the form

$$V_n=C_1\lambda_1^n+ C_2\lambda_2^n,$$

where $C_i$ are (complex) constants. The set of the solutions of the recurrence is a two-dimensional linear space, with the basis consisting of the geometric progressions $\{\lambda_1^n\}$, $\{\lambda_2^n\}$. So we search the sequence $\{V_n\}$ as a linear combination of the basis sequences in order to satisfy the initial conditions:

$\cases{V_0=C_1\lambda_1^0+ C_2\lambda_2^0=C_1+C_2\\
(1-10k)V_0=V_1=C_1\lambda_1^1+ C_2\lambda_2^1= C_1\lambda_1+ C_2\lambda_2}$.

This system has a unique solution $C_1=\frac{V_0\lambda_1}{\sqrt{D}}$ and  $C_2=\frac{-V_0\lambda_2}{\sqrt{D}}$. So

$$V_n=V_0\frac{\lambda_1^{n+1}-\lambda_2^{n+1}}{\sqrt{D}}.$$

Now we examine the convergence of the sequence $\{V_n\}$ and we even drop the restriction $k>0$.

If $D>0$ (that is if  $k<\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{10}\approx 0.03$ or $k>\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{10}\approx 0.37$) then both roots $\lambda_i$ are real and different. So the sequence $\{V_n\}$ converges iff

both $-1<\lambda_1, \lambda_2\le 1$ iff

$-2<1-10k-\sqrt{D}<1-10k+\sqrt{D}\le 2$ iff

$\sqrt{D}<1+10k$ and $\sqrt{D}\le 3-10k$ iff

$100k^2-40k+1<(1+10k)^2$ and $k<0.3$ and $100k^2-40k+1\le (3-10k)^2$ iff

$k>0$ and $k<0.3$ and $k\le 0.4$ iff

$0<k<0.3$.

Since $0.3<\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{10}\approx 0.37$, the sequence $\{V_n\}$ converges iff $0<k<\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{10}\approx  0.03$.

If $D<0$ (that is if  $0.03\approx\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{10}<k<\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{10}\approx 0.37$) then both roots $\lambda_i$ are not real. Since $\lambda_2=\overline{\lambda_1}$, then

$$V_n=C\operatorname {Im} \lambda_1^{n+1},$$ where $C$ is a constant which does not depend on $n$. So the sequence $\{V_n\}$ diverges if $|\lambda_1|\ge 1$  and converges if $|\lambda_1|<1$.  Since $|\lambda_1|=|\lambda_2|$ and $|\lambda_1\lambda_2|=|5k|=5k$, the sequence $\{V_n\}$ diverges iff $0.2=\frac 15 \le k<\frac{2+ \sqrt{13}}{20}\approx 0.28$ and converges iff  $0.03\approx\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{10}<k<\frac 15=0.2$.

If **$D=0$** (that is if $k=\frac{2\pm \sqrt{3}}{10}$) then $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda=\frac{1-10k}2\ne 0$, so we should search the formula for a sequence $\{V_n\}$ in the form

$$V_n=C_1\lambda^n+ C_2n\lambda^n,$$

where $C_i$ are (complex) constants. The set of the solutions of the recurrence is a two-dimensional linear space, with the basis consisting of the sequences $\{\lambda^n\}$, $\{n\lambda^n\}$. So we search the sequence $\{V_n\}$ as a linear combination of the basis sequences in order to satisfy the initial conditions:

$\cases{V_0=C_1\lambda^0+ C_2\cdot 0\cdot \lambda^0=C_1\\
(1-10k)V_0=V_1=C_1\lambda^1+ C_2\cdot 1\cdot \lambda^1= C_1\lambda+ C_2\lambda}$.

This system has a unique solution $C_1=C_2=\frac{V_0}2$. So

$$V_n= \frac{V_0(1+n)\lambda^n}2.$$

Equality $D=0$ implies $\lambda=\frac{-1\mp\sqrt{3}}2$. If $\lambda=\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}}2$, then $|\lambda|<1$ and the sequence $\{V_n\}$ converges to the zero. If $\lambda=\frac{-1-\sqrt{3}}2$, then $|\lambda|>1$ and the sequence $\{V_n\}$ diverges.

*Final answer*: The sequence $\{V_n\}$ converges iff $0<k<\frac 15=0.2$

*Added.* Yes, I can investigate this situation more precisely. So, it seems the following.

I recall that if the sequence polynomial has two different (real) roots $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ that is if $D>0$ that is if  $k<\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{10}\approx 0.03$ or $k>\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{10}\approx 0.37$ then

$$V_n=V_0\frac{\lambda_1^{n+1}-\lambda_2^{n+1}}{\sqrt{D}}.$$

As we showed, the sequence $\{V_n\}$ converges iff $0<k<\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{10}\approx 0.03$. In the latter case we have the following.

Since $0<\lambda_1\lambda_2=5k<1$, we have that both roots have the same sign. So

$\lambda=\lambda_1=\frac{1-10k+\sqrt{D}}2$ and $\mu=\lambda_2\frac{1-10k-\sqrt{D}}2$. Since $10k<1$, we have $1>\lambda>\mu>0$.

[image]

So $\{V_n\}$ is a sequence of positive numbers and it is a difference of two geometric progressions with positive quotients. Empirical evidence suggests that the sequence $\{V_n\}$ monotonically and quickly decreases. See, for instance the following graph for $k=0.01$:

[image]

To prove the monotony of the sequence $\{V_n\}$ we differentiate $V_n$ with respect to $n$:

$$\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{n}}=\frac{V_0}{\sqrt{D}}\left(\lambda^n\ln\lambda-\mu^n\ln\mu\right).$$

So $\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{n}}<0$ iff $\lambda^n\ln\lambda<\mu^n\ln\mu$ iff $\left(\frac{\lambda}{\mu}\right)^n\log_\mu \lambda<0$, which is true, because $1>\lambda>\mu>0$.

Comment: So why does the graph generated act the way it does? Those sequences do produce velocities less than $0.1$ in magnitude at those $n$, no?

Comment: @GFauxPas The sequence changes by discrete steps from $V_n$ to $V_{n+1}$ and this is crucial for its behavior. For the most part of your graph you have $D<0$ (it holds provided $0.03\approx\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{10}<k<\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{10}\approx 0.37$), so both roots $\lambda_i$ of the recurrence polynomial are not real, and we have $V_n=C\operatorname {Im} \lambda_1^{n+1}$. That is the sequence $\{V_n\}$ is far from being monotonic, due to rotation by $\arg\lambda_1$ effect.

Comment: If the sequence polynomial has two different real roots $\lambda$ and $\mu$, then (in general) the sequence $\{V_n\}=\{C_\lambda\lambda^n+C_\mu\mu^n\}$ asymptotically vanishes (or grows) as $\lambda^n$, where $\lambda$ is the root with largest absolute value. But there also may be distortions by a summand $C_\mu\mu^n$, when $C_\lambda$ and $C_\mu$ (or $\lambda$ and $\mu$) have different signs (the latter happens iff $k<0$), especially when $C_\mu$ is larger than $C_\lambda$.

Comment: Can you please add an explanation of these distortions in your answer? And please describe whether or not these distortions make the function unoptimizable in these intervals. Thank you :)

Comment: @GFauxPas Added.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. How did you find the coordinates with respect to the new bases? Did you use a CAS or am I missing some obvious algebra?

Comment: @GFauxPas In the answer I searched the sequence $\{V_n\}$ as a linear combination of the basis sequences in order to satisfy the initial conditions, that is a system of two linear equations.

Comment: Did you treat $\lambda$ in the system as an unknown, then? Or did you express it in terms of $k$?

Comment: @GFauxPas No, $\lambda$ is the root of the sequence polynomial with largest absolute value and $\mu$ is the other root.

Comment: This works even if the starting values don't define an eigenvector, because we can we can write it as a l.c. of eigenvectors?

Comment: @GFauxPas Yes, this is the idea.

Comment: And this also addresses the pathological case of $k = 1/10$? Thanks so much for your continued help.

Comment: @GFauxPas This is not a pathological case. It was already considered when $D<0$. For this $k$ the sequence polynomial has two different not real roots and the sequence $\{V_n\}$ diverges.

Comment: Why does using $\langle n \lambda^n  \rangle$ fix the problem of $\lambda$ having multiplicity?

Comment: @GFauxPas If I understand the theory right, this is not a problem, but forms of the basis sequences, satisfying the recurrence in this degenerated case.

Comment: I'm going over your work and most of it is great but I believe your calculation for $|\lambda| < 1$ is in error. I get that $\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{2} < k < \frac 1 5$ the sequence does converge, but erratically, because of a $\sin(\theta(n+1))$ term. This is accordance with my simulations.

Comment: @GFauxPas Thanks. Corrected. I also corrected case $D=0$ and *Final answer*, in which the lower bound still is different form $\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}2$.

Answer (score 1):

Do you remember:
Given
$${x^2} + p \cdot x + q = 0$$
and
$$D = {p^2} - 4q$$
we have the roots
$$x = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\frac{{ - p - \sqrt D }}{2}} \\ 
  {\frac{{ - p + \sqrt D }}{2}} 
\end{array}} \right.$$

As an application, we consider Fibbonacci-numbers:
$$\begin{gathered}
  {f_0} = 1,{f_1} = 1 \hfill \\
  {f_n} = {f_{n - 1}} + {f_{n - 2}} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$
and
$${f_n} = {f_{n - 1}} + {f_{n - 2}} \Leftrightarrow {f_n} - {f_{n - 1}} - {f_{n - 2}} = 0$$
We build qudratic
$${x^2} = x + 1 \Leftrightarrow {x^2} - x - 1 = 0$$
with
$$p =  - 1,q =  - 1,D = {p^2} - 4 \cdot q = 1 + 4 = 5$$
and get roots
$$x = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\frac{{1 - \sqrt D }}{2}} \\ 
  {\frac{{1 + \sqrt D }}{2}} 
\end{array}} \right.$$
With these roots we can write:
$${f_n} = \frac{1}{{\sqrt D }} \cdot \left( {{{\left( {\frac{{1 + \sqrt D }}{2}} \right)}^{n + 1}} - {{\left( {\frac{{1 - \sqrt D }}{2}} \right)}^{n + 1}}} \right) = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 5 }} \cdot \left( {{{\left( {\frac{{1 + \sqrt 5 }}{2}} \right)}^{n + 1}} - {{\left( {\frac{{1 - \sqrt 5 }}{2}} \right)}^{n + 1}}} \right)$$
We resolved the reccurence!

We are now going to apply this to your problem. Steps are exactly the same.
Given:
$$\begin{gathered}
  A(k) = 1 - 10 \cdot k,{V_0} = P \hfill \\
  {V_1}(k) = A(k) \cdot {V_0} \hfill \\
  {V_n}(k) = A(k) \cdot {V_{n - 1}}(k) - 5 \cdot k \cdot {V_{n - 2}}(k) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$
Then
$${V_n}(k) - A(k) \cdot {V_{n - 1}}(k) + 5 \cdot k \cdot {V_{n - 2}}(k) = 0$$
with quadratic
$${x^2} - A(k) \cdot x + 5 \cdot k = 0$$
Here
$$p =  - A(k),q = 5 \cdot k,D(k) = A{(k)^2} - 20 \cdot k$$
With the roots
$$x = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\frac{{A(k) - \sqrt D }}{2}} \\ 
  {\frac{{A(k) + \sqrt D }}{2}} 
\end{array}} \right.$$
Now we set, like before:
$${p_k}(n) = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {D(k)} }}\left( {{{\left( {\frac{{A(k) + \sqrt {D(k)} }}{2}} \right)}^{n + 1}} - {{\left( {\frac{{A(k) - \sqrt {D(k)} }}{2}} \right)}^{n + 1}}} \right)$$
and we have got:
$${V_n}(k) = {p_k}(n) \cdot {V_0}$$
We resolved the reccurence. So far.
What to with this? Perfect answer is given by @Alex Ravsky!

Comment: How are they straight lines?

Comment: @GFauxPas: New edit. With $k$ you are controlling the slopes.

Comment: But I'm not trying to find a form for $V_n$, I'm trying to analyze the speed of convergence of $V$.

Comment: @GFauxPas The form for ${V_n}$ is similar, but more complicated, as you can see from the polynomials in $k$. I don't know at the moment, if they have something in common with a known function. If degree in $k$ is growing, $k$ might be chosen very small.